# unable to convert from ascii-8bit to utf8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning ruby on rails so my questions might be very basic. I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0 on windows 8. First, I'm trying to install ruby on rails, but I got many errors like:

```
unable to convert from ascii-8bit to utf8 logo remix.gif, skipping
```

The installment was successful, but I think it misses some images. I have searched the web, and many said for MAC machine, it can be fixed by adding .bash_profile to \users\username with content of:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
unset LC_ALL
```

BUT how do I fix this on windows 8 machine ?

Second, how to start Webrick server on windows 8 ?
For reference, here are my list of gems:

```
actionmailer (4.0.0)
actionpack (4.0.0)
activemodel (4.0.0)
activerecord (4.0.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.0)
arel (4.0.0)
atomic (1.1.12)
backports (3.3.3)
bigdecimal (1.2.1, 1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
coderay (1.0.9)
coffee-rails (4.0.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
ffi (1.9.0)
formatador (0.2.4)
guard (1.8.2)
guard-sass (1.3.2)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (1.5.0)
jquery-rails (3.0.4)
json (1.8.0, 1.7.7)
listen (1.2.2)
lumberjack (1.0.4)
mail (2.5.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (5.0.6, 4.7.5, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.8)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pry (0.9.12.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0)
railties (4.0.0)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.0)
rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
rdoc (4.0.1, 4.0.0, 3.12.2)
rubygems-update (2.0.6)
sass (3.2.10)
sass-rails (4.0.0)
sdoc (0.3.20)
slop (3.4.6)
specific_install (0.2.3)
sprockets (2.10.0)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
test-unit (2.5.5, 2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
turbolinks (1.3.0)
tzinfo (1.0.1, 0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.2)
webrick (1.3.1)
win32console (1.3.2)
```

When I type "rails server", I got this messages:

```
   Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps]             # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                  # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc]                  # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Are there some installments I missed ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally solved the second problem and have Webrick running. Turns out, I have to create the application first like so "rails new myblog", go inside the directory "cd myblog", run "bundle install", after that I can type "rails s" to start the server. It's a bit different with apache server where apache server can be started anytime without creating any apps. Hence my confusion.

I would very much appreciate if anyone can help with my first problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the same variables as environment variables in Windows.  You can use setx from the command line (i.e. setx LC_CTYPE "en_US.UTF-8"... see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/502358/easier-way-to-change-environment-variables-in-windows-8)) and this should have the same effect as what you have above.

That being said, I don't actually have Windows 8 to test this, so you're going to have to try it yourself... but that is the Windows 8 equivalent of what you have above for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

developing rails on windows 8 is a pain. It's not linux based. You should install ubuntu

as for the `ascii-8bit to utf8` error. I had a similar problem and fixed it with

`gem install rdoc`

Then to regenerate the documentation

```
gem rdoc --all --overwrite
```

this was a post that helped me: [Ruby on Rails - unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for xxx/xxxx/xxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235293/ruby-on-rails-unable-to-convert-x89-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8-for-xxx-xxxx-x)

as far as windows 8 development try using virtualbox for an ubuntu machine

http://nitrous.io/ is a cool project that allows you to work in the cloud with development environments already set up