# Ruby on Rails - unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for xxx/xxxx/xxxx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, installation

I am installing ruby on rails 4.0.0 on my linux system , but i am getting this kind of errors **unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_route_matches.png, skipping** and many similar errors , i read [here](https://github.com/dvdxaker/Rails-Installer-for-ubuntu-13.04/issues/1) that it won't cause any effect ,but i do not understand why it is coming . Any pointers?

Comment: `skipping` is not part of the error.

Comment: What do you mean "skipping" isn't part of the error? It's part of the error output.

Answer (score 44):

You need to update / install a version of the rdoc gem that supports the conversion. Then these errors won't appear during generation of the documentation when you install rails or when you regenerate the documentation.

```
gem install rdoc
```

Then to regenerate the documentation

```
gem rdoc --all --overwrite
```

Comment: As a general practice, it's a good idea to `gem update --system` and `gem update` before installing additional gems.

Comment: `sudo gem update --system && sudo gem update && sudo gem install rdoc && sudo` `gem rdoc --all --overwrite;` worked well for me; whereas setting/exporting/changing environment variables did not.

Answer (score 6):

Set such environment variables before you do install:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using online documentation to using rdoc and ri, then you can avoid these errors and speed up your installs by skipping the rdoc and ri installations. Michael Hartl recommends this in his [book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning). Just add a .gemrc file to your home directory with the following contents:

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```